# ASUS Z170M-Plus Motherboard BIOS Update from 0408 to 0412, mob stucks in infinite on-off loop

Tags: boot, bios

I need your expertise; I am experience computer tech for past 21 years. This one really puzzle me. BTW, this is supposed to be for Adobe CC WS

**Quick Hardware Spec:** * Z170M-Plus stock BIOS was 0219, I7-6700K, TT Contact 21 HSF, 4x KT HyperX Fury DDR4 8GB, 1x Samsung Evo 850 500GB, 2x Seagate ST2000DM001, ASUS Strix R7-370 2GB, TT SP-750P PSU, CM N400 Chassis. ==> All hardware was previously tested separately, so should be all ok

** Problem **
1. Last week update from stock bios to v0408 --> no problem
2. Yesterday, notice new version 0412, I decided to update to it, because I am planning to reload OS with W10x64 anyway
3. After update, system reboot, and stay in boot on for few sec, and off, and on in loop
4. Jump Clr BIOS, Remove Battery, Remove Video Card to use stock GPU --> same problem
5. Called ASUS component support in Indiana --> Tech suggested to get mobo replaced. But I am not really convince yet.
6. Next step of actions when I am back to work is to take mobo out of chassis, and try again. 
7. Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to replace the motherboard the firmware is clearly corrupted.  I am to lazy to confirm if the motherboard has a backup firmware, if you have triggered that functionality if it exists and it still does not work then you are out of luck.  *Looking at the product page, knowing how that feature is listed, ASUS CrashFree BIOS 3 was listed*  Check the manual on how to initiate it.

Comment: CrashFree BIOS 3 isn't going to be enough.  The motherboard does have a hardware button to recovery the firmware.  In the current state your motherboard is machine CashFree BIOS 3 cannot be used after reading the documentation.

Comment: I have read the manual inside out already. CrashFree BIOS3 --> you supposed to be able to recover the BIOS using USB stick, or using ASUS motherboard disk. BUT, the problem is the mobo don't even stay on or post anything on screen to perform the recovery. I guess this mobo has been bricked... Just want to check with you guys if there is any miracle ...

Comment: There is a separate feature with a hardware button that lets you switch between the primary and a secondary copy of the firmware.  Your motherboard does not have that feature.

Comment: I have 2nd identical motherboard Z170M-Plus, shipped with same 0219 BIOS, I was courageous to try the BIOS 0412 update again with all the same HW, except this new MB. --> BIOS 0412 flashed ok, and the new board is still alive! So, what caused the BIOS flash to kill the 1st motherboard?

Comment: That is impossible to determine and is the reasons warranties were created.

Comment: Totally true, I am just being curious about it. 2 Identical motherboards, with same major components....both updating to BIOS 0412. 1st one from 0408 to 0412, 2nd one from 0219 to 0412. 1st one was rendered dead after BIOS update..... ??? so weird